# Does SharePoint 2007 has any Client SDK available?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

We have a SharePoint server 2007 and we are trying to make few entries into the SharePoint using the c#.net code. I came to know that we can use the SharePoint Client SDK components. But no where I found the SDK for 2007 version of SharePoint .

Is it possible to use the SharePoint 2013 Client SDK components to access the SharePoint  2007 site and do all the get or update actions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since SharePoint Client Components SDK consists of collection of client-side object model (CSOM) DLLs and CSOM is **not** supported in SharePoint 2007, there is **no** release of SharePoint Client SDK for 2007 version.

But you could utilize [SharePoint 2007 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for that purpose, the following example demonstrates how to consume SharePoint Web Services to create a List Item:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace SharePoint.Client
{
    public class ListsClient : IDisposable
    {
        public ListsClient(Uri webUri, ICredentials credentials)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Credentials = credentials;
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }

        public ListsClient(Uri webUri)
        {
            _client = new Lists.Lists();
            _client.Url = webUri + "/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Create a List Item 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listName">List Name</param>
        /// <param name="propertyValues">List Item properties</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public XmlNode CreateListItem(string listName,Dictionary<string,string> propertyValues)
        {
            var payload = new XmlDocument();
            var updates = payload.CreateElement("Batch");
            updates.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            var method = payload.CreateElement("Method");
            method.SetAttribute("ID", "1");
            method.SetAttribute("Cmd", "New");
            foreach (var propertyValue in propertyValues)
            {
                var field = payload.CreateElement("Field");
                field.SetAttribute("Name", propertyValue.Key);
                field.InnerText = propertyValue.Value;
                method.AppendChild(field);
            }
            updates.AppendChild(method);
            return _client.UpdateListItems(listName, updates);
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            _client.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        protected Lists.Lists _client;  //SharePoint Web Services Lists proxy

    }
}
```

**Usage**

How to create a Task item:

```
using (var client = new SPOListsClient(webUrl, userName, password))
{
    var taskProperties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    taskProperties["Title"] = "Order approval";
    taskProperties["Priority"] = "(2) Normal";
    var result = client.CreateListItem(listTitle, taskProperties);    
}
```

### References

- [SharePoint 2007 Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862916%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
- [Lists.UpdateListItems Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the 2013 SDK can be used for 2007 instances, but I know that the SharePoint 2007 SDK is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?amp&id=79).

Comment: i installed this sdk . where do I see the dlls after I install the sdk ? normally C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI is the path where I would see the 2010 sdk dlls.

Comment: Unfortunately the link you have provided is NOT SharePoint Client SDK. Since CSOM is not supported in SharePoint 2007, there is no release of SharePoint Client SDK for 2007 version.